# The way to implement User Email Preferences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to implement a feature which lets every user decide the kind of emails he/she will receive. So far, I can only see the user receiving emails when he/she receives a friendship request and when he/she receives a new message. The way I plan to implement this is as follows:

1. Each User `has_one` EmailPreference
2. EmailPreferences table will have 2 columns: Friendship (Boolean) and Message (Boolean).
3. By default, they will be true. So the User will receive emails for both new messages and new requests received.
4. The user can go to the Edit action and update the values as per his choice.
5. I plan on using an `if statement` which will check if `@user.emailpreference.message?` or `@user.emailpreference.friendship?` before the send email method.

I'd like to know if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: I guess, not sure if it will work or if there is a simpler way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple considerations - I'd question whether you want to do the has_one or simply add the columns to the user.  I also tend to use dates instead of booleans, so you can see when the boolean was set.  For naming, consider something other than 'friendship' and 'message'.  If it is an attribute on the user, I'd consider something like 'subscribed_to_friendships' and 'subscribed_to_messages'.

The reason I avoid has_one's in general is to make very simple queries and reduce the need for maintenance.  It's likely you'll be getting all users that should receive a message and looping through them, I prefer to avoid the joins and keep it simple.  I also don't really like how false and null are the same on the child.  This will help you avoid deleting/adding preference records, especially if the default is true and you're going to create preferences for most users by default.

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue in the approach is that if tomorrow you have more type as preference , means when somebody joins than also you want to send the email , in that case you have to add one more column. Why do not you normalize it further and use more table to store the Preference type

```
             Id Name
             1  Friendship
             2  Message

             Id  User Id Flag
             1      1     TRUE
             2      1     False
```

It means user 1 is opted for Friendship but not for Message. Now you can easily add any new preference.

Answer (score 0):

the approach by https://stackoverflow.com/users/177489/swards is for me , the best option because that has_one queries can be a mess later.
add columns to user model and gg!